# Touch listener responding even I don't click on button

Tags: java, android

Well I have a sample code from another question, is an "always on top button app" and is responding at every touch on the screen.
Can anyone help me with this problem? 
I want that the  app respond only when I press the button..
Here is the code:

```
public class HUD extends Service implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener {
Button mButton;
@Override
public IBinder
onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //mView = new HUDView(this);

    mButton = new Button(this);
    mButton.setText("Screenshot");
    mButton.setClickable(true);
    mButton.setOnTouchListener(this);


    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.setTitle("Load Average");
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mButton, params);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mButton != null)
    {
        ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mButton);
        mButton = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Overlay button event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //where it seems to be the problem
    return false;
}


}
```

Thank you, even if you can not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be this line of code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
```

You can learn more about this from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH). Why do you have this line in your code?

Comment: Glad it did, be sure to accept the answer as well. Best of luck in your future coding.